# 'geth --mine' is unable to resume synchronisation after ctrl-c and restart

Tags: go-ethereum

I am just trying out `geth` to get myself familiar with the technology. I understand CPU mining is not practical given the hashrate disparity with other GPU based miners.

At the begining I ran `geth` to download the block chain.

After it is done, I tried to run a miner process: `geth --etherbase 1 --mine --port 0`.

It seems to run alright. Operation ran as expected.

Then I want to fine tune the process. I want to allow more cache for the `geth --mine` to use.

I ctrl-C the process, then  bring up

```
geth --etherbase 1 --mine --cache 4096 --port 0
```

Now in the log I can see many

```
WARN [12-02|14:45:53] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block body download canceled (requested)"
WARN [12-02|14:46:23] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block header download canceled (requested)"
```

It seems like the miner is unable to sync and catch up. I have ctrl-c again and run only `geth` to catch up. I can verify in `geth console` it has caught up to the latest block. Restart miner. Some errors again.

Some people suggested to run `geth upgradedb` but it seems like this command is no longer available.

Currently using osx Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0. `geth` is installed by way of `brew` and the version is 1.7.3

Comment: Why do you use `--port 0`? That is the port used to synchronize with other nodes and keep the blockchain updated. Unless you have a reason I'd suggest to use the default port if you want to mine.

Comment: Always has this `30303 address already used` problem. My platform is macos. `--port 0` is the workaround. What impact it has on mining?

Comment: To solo mine you need the blockchain fully synchronized.